# magit-diff-visit-file key bindings

Tags: magit, diff

While point is inside a diff in a Magit buffer I press `RET`, which invokes `magit-diff-visit-file`.

After checking this file, I want to quit it and get back to the Magit buffer that was previously showing.

I type `q`, it does the job but it always says that I start `keyboard-macro` recording.

So two questions here:

1. What does `q` actually do in the buffer shown by `magit-diff-visit-file`?
2. How can I list all the commands in the buffer after I run the `magit-diff-visit-file` command?

Comment: While in `magit-diff-visit-file` do `C-h k q` to find out what `q` does.

Comment: I corrected your question to say what I believe you are asking. E.g. pressing `RET` in a `diff-mode` buffer does not invoke `magit-diff-visit-file`. `diff-mode` is not part of Magit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To see what command is bound to some key `X` type <kbd>C-h k X</kbd>. In this case it should tell you that it is bound to `magit-kill-this-buffer` or if `magit-diff-visit-file` took you to the working tree version of the file `self-insert-command`.
2. You can use <kbd>C-h b</kbd> to do that in any buffer.

I don't know why pressing <kbd>q</kbd> tells you that you are starting `keyboard-macro` recording. That has something to to with your local configuration. Try to produce the issue without your customizations. You might want to use [`magit-emacs-Q-command`](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Debugging-Tools.html) to get some help with that.